# Visual Studio: How to stop breakpoint hit from stealing focus?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, focus, breakpoints

When a **breakpoint** is **hit** in Visual Studio, it **steals the focus** from whatever *other* application the programmer is viewing/typing into at that moment. This can be very irritating since VS grabs any keyboard input the programmer was typing into the other application at that moment and takes that input as its own.

What are the tricks you folks use to prevent this focus steal?

(I face this on Visual C++ 2008 and 2010. I am guessing it is a problem for Visual Studio in general and for all recent versions.)

Comment: This is not a Visual Studio issue. This is a feature of the Windows operating system.

Comment: I'm still waiting on a usable solution to this.  I  turn breakpoints on and off continuously  during the day.  None of the answers so far helps.

Comment: For those looking for VSCode but brought here by Google: `debug.focusWindowOnBreak`

Answer (score 33):

This is finally fixed in VS2019.   Go to Tools->Options->Debugging->General, down at the bottom is "Bring Visual Studio to the foreground when breaking in the debugger."
Just de-select it and you will no longer be interrupted while  multitasking.

[image]

Comment: This works amazing, but now I'm annoyed that the task bar item no longer lights up when a breakpoint is hit...

Comment: Yeah, I will forget I'm debugging sometimes and then have to open VS to see I'm on a breakpoint.  But it's so much better than getting randomly interrupted while typing!

Comment: I decided to create a feature request for Visual Studio regarding highlighting the task bar: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/790650/highlight-the-task-bar-item-when-a-breakpoint-is-h.html

Comment: Does anyone know if we can get it to stop flashing the taskbar as well?  It's making me anxious!

Comment: File > Preferences > Settings. Type in search: "Debug: Focus Window On Break"

Answer (score 17):

This is a registry setting. See `ForegroundLockTimeout` at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957208.aspx. Zero allows applications to steal focus. *TweakUI* sets this value to 200000 when "Prevent applications from stealing focus" is checked.

For more control, download the *Tweak UI* utility of *Powertoys for Windows XP*. In the "General" tab, select "Focus" and check "Prevent applications from stealing focus".

- Google search for *ForegroundLockTimeout* at http://www.google.com/search?q=ForegroundLockTimeout
- Bing search for *Prevent applications from stealing focus* at http://www.bing.com/search?q=Prevent+applications+from+stealing+focus
- *Applications Stealing Focus on Windows XP* at http://mycvs.org/archives/2004/11/16/applications-stealing-focus-on-windows-xp for screen capture of *TweakUI*.
- *Please Don't Steal My Focus*, Coding Horror, Jeff Atwood at http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/please-dont-steal-my-focus.html

  > The strange thing is, there are
  >   provisions built into the operating
  >   system to protect us from badly
  >   written, focus stealing applications.
  >   The **ForegroundLockTimeout** registry
  >   setting is expressly designed to
  >   prevent applications from stealing
  >   focus from the user. The OS silently
  >   converts that inappropriate focus
  >   stealing behavior into friendlier,
  >   less invasive taskbar button flashing,
  >   which is the subject of the
  >   **ForegroundFlashCount** registry setting.
- *How To Prevent Programs from Stealing Focus in Windows XP* at http://www.howtodothings.com/computers-internet/how-to-prevent-programs-from-stealing-focus-in-windows-xp

Comment: The value of ForegroundLockTimeout in my registry on Windows 7 is 0x30d40 (200000) already and yet I see VStudio stealing focus when a breakpoint is hit.

Comment: I confirm this answer addresses the focus-stealing behaviour of virtually every application but Visual Studio.

Comment: Unfortunately Visual Studio appears to not care about this setting.

Comment: @RyanTernier; Which OS? I notice that Windows 7 has its own idea about application focus.

Comment: @AMissico Windows 7. Yea, it plays by it's own rules.

Comment: Microsoft's hobby is bypassing their own features.  They think they own the place.  It's bloody annoying.

Comment: I can confirm that this issue still occurs with this registry setting on Visual Studio 2013 running on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: See my answer above https://stackoverflow.com/a/46785877/514793 
for a Windows 7+ solution. It's crude but it does the job.

Comment: It takes advantage of the fact that Microsoft "think they own the place" ;-)

Comment: A windows update allowed this setting to start working. This prevented focus from being transferred when expected. e.g. I was unable to click icons on the taskbar and have them show on top.

Answer (score 9):

Right click the breakpoint and select When hit ... this will allow you to run a function when the breakpoint is hit. You can use this to print status messages to the output window. You application will keep focus.

Comment: This is very useful -- I use this technique a lot (though it can really slow down the app)

Comment: Yea, this is pretty useful! I was testing some WinForms behavior involving `Focus` and VS was messing me up pretty bad. This method solved my problem (since the fix/hack marked as answer doesn't Win 7).

Answer (score 4):

By accident I discovered a workaround, which I've been using for a few years now and while I haven't tested it in 2008 and 2010, it certainly works in 2013, '15 & '17 and at least Windows 7 & 10.

It relies on the fact that **Visual Studio will not steal focus if another Visual Studio instance is paused in execution.** Obviously the only thing as special as VS is another VS. :-/

Open a second instance of VS with a simple project. Pause the execution of the project anyway you like (e.g. put a breakpoint on the first line of execution and debug), you can then simply minimise that VS and none of the VS instances you're actually using will steal focus.

This is is obviously a heavy weight solution, but if you have ample RAM (the CPU usage of the idle VS doesn't even register for me), it works well. I haven't tried it with inter-version instances (e.g. pausing in '13 to make '17 behave), but if that works you'll probably want to opt to use the older version instance as your "dummy" VS to cut down on resource use.

Comment: This is the only suggested solution that works, yet it too heavy for me to use.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use [`OutputDebugString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362(VS.85).aspx) function to output current state into the debugger output window. You just place Visual Studio in background, position the debugged program window so that the "Output" window is visible - and no focus transition ever happens.

You will perhaps want to use macros for conditional compilation so that tracing code is not included into the release builds.