# How do I prevent the Visual Studio debugger from focusing the window when a breakpoint is hit?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio: How to stop breakpoint hit from stealing focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235373/visual-studio-how-to-stop-breakpoint-hit-from-stealing-focus)

Many times I will set a break point in Visual Studio and run a process that might take seconds or a minute or two. While that runs, I will do something else, usually other coding in another window. When the breakpoint is hit, Visual Studio gains focus and my next several keystrokes go into the debugger and all hell breaks lose depending on what my kestrokes are. (expecially in Visual C++). This is especially annoying the longer it takes to get to the breakpoint since I have to restart all over again.

Bottom line, is there a way to turn off the auto focusing feature in Visual Studio or Windows in general?

Comment: I know what your talking about. It used to drive me mad, but I couldn't find a way around it. I raised a connect issue about a year ago on, nothing so far.

Answer (score 2):

You cant stop it but you can hack around it, by setting a hit counter, so it only breaks when it reaches a certiain hit count, just right click the break point and go to hit count to do this.

[image]